# Need regex for input with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need regex so that only these characters are allowed to type:

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 & , . – / ( ) @ * + ! ? “ ‘ : ;

Also it would be nice if I could implement this through jQuery in this code:

```
$("#firstText").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  $(".zetin16").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: Have you made at least *minimal* effort to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: 'Regix' gives the answer @nicael

Comment: This isn't a question...it's a demand for code. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. Please read [ask] and show us some of your research efforts that didn't work as expected

Comment: What? I don't even had any experience of writing regex. Is it hard?

Comment: Yes...regex is complicated....searching the internet isn't though. Asking questions here should not be your research starting point. You are expected to do that first

Comment: Is there are any generators?

Comment: *"Is there are any generators"* ... isn't that a google search?

Comment: I saw few. But are they good? Can u recommend?

Comment: The [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a popular one because you can test different regex flavors. Then [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) has a good reference and is userfriendly, but only for the javascript supported regex. And then there's [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) that can show it a bit graphical.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
^[A-Z0-9&,.\/()@*+!?“‘:;-]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Will only allow these characters `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&,.–/()@*+!?“‘:;`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/bO2zN4/1

## Explanation

```
^ assert position at start of a line
[A-Z0-9&,.\/()@*+!?“‘:;-]+ match a single character present in the list below
    A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    &,. a single character in the list &,. literally (case sensitive)
    \/ matches the character / literally
    ()@*+!?“‘:;- a single character in the list ()@*+!?“‘:;- literally
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of a line
```